# Search inside hash in another class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I have the following structure:

policies/permissions

Inside permissions folder:

```
car.rb
bus.rb
bike.rb
```

Every permission file has a hash:

```
MAPPING = {
   create: [:admin]
   delete: [:admin]
   etc
}
```

On Permission class (policies folder) I have the following method to check permissions:

```
class Permission
   def self.keys_for(model)
     # ?
   end
end
```

How can I dynamically search the MAPPING hash based on the model that is being passed as parameter ?

Thanks.

Comment: model name we can consider as car, bus, bike, right ?

Comment: sorry, yes, model names are Car, Bus, Bike

Comment: Posted an answer that gets you the whole `MAPPING` hash, but maybe you just wanted the keys of that hash? Can you clarify?

Comment: yes I need to get the whole hash.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Permission
  def self.keys_for(model_name)
    eval(model_name).const_get(:MAPPING)
  end
end
```

But, have you considered an implementation in which `Permission` is a [concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) that gets included into each model so that you don't have to pass the classes around explicitly?

Comment: thanks, the problem is that model variable is a string: "Bike", "Car" etc. Is there a way to bind this string to a model based on the name ?

Comment: Ok, updated it for that scenario. Thought it was the class because of the variable name.

Comment: Also, if you *can* pass in the class, that'd be cleaner than using `eval`, which is usually a code smell.

Comment: @gui12344455 Awesome! It's customary on SO to upvote/accept helpful answers ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Permission
  def self.keys_for(model)
    f = File.open("#{model}.rb") #f give you the permissions hash
  end
end
```

**notes** : make sure that model param is the same as file name and also take care for path of files.

Hope you got my point